# Cannot request parameters using spring e thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, spring, forms, thymeleaf

I can't send parameters from view to control using Spring thymeleaf. This is my controller:

```
@GetMapping(value="/adminP")
public String adminParameter(
    @RequestParam(value = "p", required = false) String p,
    Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("p", p);
    System.out.println("The parameter is " + p);
    return "adminPage";
}
```

And this is the form (I'm using a bootstrap modal):

```
<div id="modalBody" class="modal-body"> 
   <form th:action="@{/adminP}" method="get">
      <input type="text" th:name="p">
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="submit" th:name="action" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Confirm</button>
   </form>
</div>
```

When I send the form, the console doesn't print.

Do you know where's the problem?

Thank you all

Comment: I noticed that the same form works if is out from the boostrap modal

Comment: The problem was data-dismiss="modal", removing that it works